# How to group based on the count of a string attribute equaling a value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and I've managed to narrow it down to this:

```
Event        | Response
------------ | ------
Birthday     | Yes
Anniversary  | No
Anniversary  | No
Birthday     | Yes
Birthday     | Yes
```

I want to count the number of 'yes' replies for each event, so the end product should be:

```
Event        | numYes
------------ | ------
Birthday     | 3
Anniversary  | 0
```

I imagine it uses `group by Event` and an aggregator for `Response = 'yes'`, but I'm not sure how to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select event, sum(Response = 'Yes') numYes
from your_table
group by event;
```

It uses the fact that true is 1 and false is 0 in MySQL and results in shorter expression.

Another way of achieving the same thing is using `COUNT` like this:

```
select event, count(case when Response = 'Yes' then 1 end) numYes
from your_table
group by event;
```

Comment: Thanks, still new to SQL and must have skipped over `sum` in my readings. Was trying to use `count`

Comment: @Tom Take a look at the update answer now. Added a few details and another query using COUNT

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT   Event, SUM(Response='Yes') numYes    
FROM     tablename
GROUP BY Event
```

Which will select the Event column and sum all the rows where a Response='Yes' for that event and place the result in a column called "numYes". You then group by Event to get a unique instance for each event.

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you edit it to explain why this is the answer.

Comment: @Blackwood added some wording